# return list of columns that exceeds character length limit - pyspark/snowflake

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing an issue where I am not able to return the list of all columns that exceeds the character length while writing a dataframe to a table in snowflake using pyspark.

how can I return the list of columns at a time instead of updating each column, rerun the command and then face same issue on another column and repeating the process till all columns length is fixed.

```
(df.write \
    .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) 
    .options(**sfWriteOptions) 
    .option("schema",schemaname) 
    .option("dbtable",targettable) 
    .mode('overwrite') 
    .save())

net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: User character length limit (30) exceeded by string
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake is pretty unique in that you don't have benefits to defining the length of a string (or even integers) in your table.  There is no space or performance benefits to it.  So, one thought would be to redefine your tables so that they don't have length defined.  If that isn't possible, perhaps create a temporary table that has no lengths, load from spark to that table and then evaluate the field lengths before inserting into your final table.

I'm not aware of a more dynamic way to do that before loading the data into Snowflake.

Comment: Thanks for responding Mike. the snowflake tables need to be defined with column lengths as part of the requirements. one option that I can think of is to fetch max of every column and then do a cross check against the snowflake table column lengths. But, I felt it will be time taking process as the number of columns can exceed 200 most of the time.

Comment: What are the requirements on what to do with data that exceeds the length?  Are you supposed to truncate it or remove the record as bad?

Comment: If you are interested in having the values truncated, you should check out this URL that allows you to use `truncate_columns` option for the connector, which will essentially turn on the `TRUNCATECOLUMNS` option of the `COPY INTO` command, which is what the connector leverages in the background.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#required-context-options

Comment: I need to update the snowflake table schema so that there will not be any truncation happening while loading the data into the columns. the current situation is that I can only find out the text that is exceeding the length of a column. So, I have to manually search with the value, make the changes for the column length and then reload the table again only to find some other column data comes up in the error log .

Comment: my intention is to see an option where after executing df.write command, the error message will list of all the columns whose length has been exceeded.

Comment: @Venkat - we're back to Mike's original answer. If you don't want the text to be truncated then _don't define a column length for the string fields_, it doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: @SimonD - I agree. but as per the requirements, the column length needs to be defined in the snowflake table. what I am looking for is to see if there is an option where the name of the column(s) will be returned from snowflake or pyspark when column length issue occurs. if there no defined approach, then I have no other option but to manually check for the column length or try to come up with a code/udf to compare max length of each dataframe to the length of the table in snowflake before loading.

Comment: I think it would be best to speak to the users and dig a little deeper around the user requirements rather than accepting them as set in stone. It doesn't make any sense to provide column lengths for `varchar` fields if you don't need to. Do you know why they require this?